# android OAuthCommunicationException addThis

Tags: android, sdk, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, addthis

I am currently using the android Library of addThis, it allows me to easily shares things on twitter, facebook and so on...
Though, when I change the minSDKVersion or the targetSDKVersion in the Android Manifest to 10 or higher the Twitter Sharing doesn't work.
I do use addThis0.0.6 (I can't make the 0.0.7 work ...) and signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1 and signpost-core-1.2.1.1 (as I could read on support of addThis).
I do get the error:

```
oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: null
```

But I call the AddThis.shareItem() function into a different Thread than the UI one (in an AsyncTask).

why then?

Comment: Are you directly calling signpost, or is this done from addThis automatically?

Comment: this is done by addThis. Basicaly I just call one and only one function of the AddThis class to tweet my text.